# global variable multiple reader one writer multithread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition

I'm trying to write a program in C++ with one global variable is read by multiple threads and updated by one thread.  In this case do I need to write any semaphore like things or can I just leave it as is since only 1 thread is actually writing to the global variable so there is no possible race conditions.

Also Im a newbie in semaphore so I need to spare myself the hassle if possible.

The program is this:
writer thread: check pin constantly for high voltage, set global variable when it is high

reader threads: constantly check global variable in infinite loop and do something when it is set.

Answer (score 4):

It’s simple: if more than one thread can access an object at the same time without synchronization and at least one of those threads is writing to the object, the program has a data race. The behavior of a program that has a data race is undefined.

You can provide synchronization by preventing simultaneous access with a mutex, or, in many cases, by using an atomic object.

If you don’t properly synchronize reads and writes you can enjoy the popular parlor game of “Guessing What This Program Might Do”. There are lots of message threads that provide rationalizations for why a data race is okay under some set of circumstances. That’s fine if you don’t really care whether your program actually works correctly. If you do care, synchronize.

Comment: alright imma use atomic in this case cause its easier

Comment: @bakalolo — yes, this is a perfect candidate for an atomic variable. The standard library implementor for your target hardware knows more about the hardware than you or I do, and will have done what’s necessary to make it work right.

Comment: If there are not many writes, the atomic variable solutions is faster. If it would change a lot then a compareAndSwap (atomic operation) would cause a lot of retries. 

The synchronized solutions with mutexes usually only allows one thread to access the variable. In other programming languages there are reader-writer locks and maybe also available in the standard library for c++. It would be possible to build a reader-writer lock with mutex (but do not do that :-) )

Comment: @thomas -- I see that C++17 has added [std::shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex), which says that it can be used for read-many write-rarely situations.

Comment: That is a read-write lock. You have the lock/unlock function and also the lock_shared/unlock_shared function. Shared means several threads can access the protected ressource/variable

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide more context, but in general you should guard access to this variable using some kind of synchronization primitive like [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex). You may relax requirements if you don't care if some thread may read incorrect value, but that all depends on your use case.

You can simplify and replace "multiple readers" from your question by "single reader", and the answer would still be: you have to guard access to the shared variable from different threads, otherwise reader thread may not "observe" the change that was made by the writer thread and essentially end up reading and using wrong value.

If it's a simple integer that you are trying to read/modify from your threads, then you may use [std::atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: so ur saying that mutex is optional but atomic is mandatory?  No I dont care if the value is wrong sometimes

Comment: If you don't care for correctness, then you can simply use volatile specifier, but in that case "reader" thread won't "see" updated value for some time. It's difficult to say without some example program or context.

Comment: I made some context see my new post and then you can let me know

Comment: For your case you can use std::atomic, you can also simply use volatile if you don't care that readers may not see immediately updated value. You may simply make it all simple and simply use std::mutex and make it really thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say without knowing what would constitute a *correct* program in your particular case. But it's true that you won't need to worry about corrupting the memory as long as you have only one concurrent writer.

Multiple readers will get indeterminate values without locking, though. You'll definitely want to use [atomic loads (seq_cst, most likely) and stores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) to the value, and you might want to look into the `volatile` keyword to prevent storing the value in a register if that's a concern in your application.

Comment: volatile absolutely won't help help here.

Comment: @Pavel - I'm not sure why you say that. If the global variable is a bare int then passing it into a function that takes a volatile int reference is the difference between reloading the value and caching it. See this [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ToE2-_) for several different scenarios.

Comment: In seems by OP's requirement it would be ok to use volatile (but then there is no thread safety involved at all). However, `volatile` in no way would provide thread safety. Even regular atomic may not provide, it depends on [memory_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) that you use with atomics.

Comment: Your godbolt absolutely shows that it won't be thread safe :) Once a thread writes to some memory cell other threads may not "observe" the change for some time (like a thousand cycles for example). Only proper memory barrier could guarantee memory synchronization between threads.

Comment: Sorry I didn't say why it "absolutely shows", while in fact your posted code shows opposite, I didn't review asm originally :) x86 has strong memory model, so it happens to be the same code generated when using volatile. On ARM for example it absolutely won't be the same. Add ARM compiler to your example and you'll see.

Comment: [Sample ARM code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/omX9B6) Check our [weak vs strong memory models](https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/)

Comment: "*But it's true that you won't need to worry about corrupting the memory as long as you have only one concurrent writer.*" What standard can I find that guarantee in? And even if that was true, how can he possibly know how many writers he has? Nothing in the C++ standard prevents code that appears to only read an object from internally writing to it. (And this has actually happened and actually caused code to break!)